# Assign Linux Command to Variable in Groovy

Tags: linux, curl, groovy

I'm attempting to run a linux command, curl, through groovy, and would like the output to be assign to a variable. I'd like to do this, so I can extract specific data from the curl output, and use in in m y groovy script.

Any ideas, how I can do this.

I've tried,

```
def after = "curl \"https://test.com\"".execute()
def after = "curl \"https://test.com\"".execute().text
```

but the variable is always empty. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not `new URL('https://test.com').text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

linux command with spaces needs to be separated.

```
["/bin/sh", "-o", "your_command"].execute()
```

In your case it would be something like below:

```
["curl", "https://test.com"].execute()
```

OR

```
def after = ["curl", "https://test.com"].execute().text
```

Try and see if it works.